# Error While Changing Wifi-Adapter To Monitor Mode on VMware

Tags: vmware, kali-linux, wireless-adapter

So i'm doing a hacking course on Udemy and trying to do the airodump-ng commands myself and i bought a new external wireless adapter for it and it connects perfectly to the host device, but when i try to change it to the monitor mode, it just doesn't happen. Here are the inputs and outputs of the terminal:

```
root@kali:~# airmon-ng
PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset

null    wlan0           r8188eu         Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter

root@kali:~# airmon-ng start wlan0
Found 2 processes that could cause trouble.
Kill them using 'airmon-ng check kill' before putting
the card in monitor mode, they will interfere by changing channels
and sometimes putting the interface back in managed mode

   PID Name
   497 NetworkManager
   682 wpa_supplicant

PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset

null    wlan0           r8188eu         Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter

root@kali:~# airmon-ng check kill

Killing these processes:

PID Name
682 wpa_supplicant

root@kali:~# ifconfig wlan0 down
root@kali:~# iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

I wanna know why is this error happening, what does it mean and how can i fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error likely means the wireless card does not support Monitor mode. Numerous wireless cards do not support monitor mode. Ask at your school what cards will support monitor mode.

Answer (score 0):

On no occasion should you kill the Network manager.
In the above report, it appears that you have killed the network manager and you can not create a monitor mode interface when the network manager is down.
Turn up up the network manager and manually kill the processes that could cause trouble using the `kill` command.

```
 PID   Name
 497   NetworkManager
```

In addition, not all wireless card are ideal for wireless hacking.
A good example of cheap wireless card which could serve is [Alfa AWUS036H USB](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Alfa-AWUS036NHV-802-11n-Super-High-Power-1500mW-WIRELESS-N-USB-Wi-Fi-adapter/171362285614?epid=1328600761&hash=item27e5fcf82e:g:DqkAAOSwBvNTopIh) wireless Wi-Fi adapter.